# Update Form Text on mouse move

Tags: c#, mouseevent

I have a simple form and I want to display the Cursor position updated  continually as the user moves the mouse.  The problem I am running into is that the text does not update when the mouse is moved.

```
public void mouse_position(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
    TextBox textBox1 = new TextBox();
    Label label1 = new Label();

    // Initialize the controls and their bounds.

    label1.Location = new Point(1400, 500);
    label1.Size = new Size(10, 10);
    label1.BringToFront();
    label1.BackColor = Color.Aqua;

    // Add the Label control to the form's control collection.
    Controls.Add(label1);
    label1.Text = Cursor.Position.Y.ToString();

 }
```

Like I said, it gives me the initial mouse location but never updates

Comment: Which event handler is that? MouseUp, MouseDown or MouseMove? You shouldn't rename standard `controlName_EventName` handlers, rather make a new method and call it from handler.

Comment: You would only want to create controls like this **ONCE**, not on every movement.  Creation could be done in the Load() event of the form.  To access it via `label1`, however, you'd have to declare it at class/form level (not locally in that method).  Any reason for creating the controls dynamically instead of dropping them on the form via the designer?

Comment: *"when the mouse is moved"* - where do you move the mouse? The [MouseMove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.mousemove) event is only rised for control, e.g. `Form`, but as soon as you mouseover its child - you won't get this event rised on parent. You will need to use another technique, e.g. all children have to subscribe to `MouseMove` and call some method of form which will update coordinates.

Comment: If you want to get movement across **all** controls in your entire application, look at implementing [IMessageFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.imessagefilter?view=netframework-4.8).  I have [an example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55078800/2330053) that you could start from.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   int mouseX = e.X;
   int mouseY = e.Y;

   textBox1.Text = "X: " + e.X.ToString() + "Y: " + e.Y.ToString();

}
```

Basically everytime you move your mouse on your form, textbox1 will update with the X/Y positions of the mouse.

Output (For demonstration purposes only):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use the event

```
public event System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler MouseMove;
```